# Detect and correct grouping variables with more than one repetition of a time sequence

Tags: r

I have a database with wrong personal identifier `id`. 
I would like to find an *automatic* method of detection and correction but I can not figure it out.

I only find out the *manual* way to do it (quite cumbersome).

The data look like this

```
   id time
1   1    1
2   1    2
3   1    3
4   2    1
5   2    2
6   2    3
7   2    1
8   2    2
9   2    3
10  3    1
11  3    2
12  3    3
13  3    1
14  3    2
15  3    3
```

`id` 2 and `id` 3 are incorrect because of the information we have from the `time` variable. Each time that the `time` begin, the `id` should change.

I create a count row variable and a `flag` (corrected) `id` variable.

```
dta$row = 1:nrow(dta)
dta$id_f = dta$id
```

Then I correct the cases manually

```
dta[4:6, 'id_f'] <- paste( dta[4:6, 'id_f'], 'a', sep = '')
dta[7:9, 'id_f'] <- paste( dta[7:9, 'id_f'], 'b', sep = '')

dta[10:12, 'id_f'] <- paste( dta[10:12, 'id_f'], 'a', sep = '')
dta[13:15, 'id_f'] <- paste( dta[13:15, 'id_f'], 'b', sep = '')
```

Do you have any clue how I could avoid doing it *by hand* ?

The output I want is the following with the `id` corrected

```
   id time row id_f
1   1    1   1    1
2   1    2   2    1
3   1    3   3    1
4   2    1   4   2a
5   2    2   5   2a
6   2    3   6   2a
7   2    1   7   2b
8   2    2   8   2b
9   2    3   9   2b
10  3    1  10   3a
11  3    2  11   3a
12  3    3  12   3a
13  3    1  13   3b
14  3    2  14   3b
15  3    3  15   3b
```

The data

```
dta = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), time = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", "time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

```
do.call(rbind, 
        by(dta, dta$id, function(x){

          # identify cases with more than one "Each time that the time begin"
          # I used "more than one 1" as criteria
          if(sum(x$time == 1) > 1){

            # diff: to detect non-consecutive times, i.e. differences not equal to one.
            # cumsum: to create an index variable, used to index letters
            x$id2 <- paste0(x$id, letters[cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(x$time) != 1)) + 1])

          # for id with a correct sequence of "time", just use the original id
          } else {
            x$id2 <- x$id
          }
          x
        }))

#      id time id2
# 1.1   1    1   1
# 1.2   1    2   1
# 1.3   1    3   1
# 2.4   2    1  2a
# 2.5   2    2  2a
# 2.6   2    3  2a
# 2.7   2    1  2b
# 2.8   2    2  2b
# 2.9   2    3  2b
# 3.10  3    1  3a
# 3.11  3    2  3a
# 3.12  3    3  3a
# 3.13  3    1  3b
# 3.14  3    2  3b
# 3.15  3    3  3b
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you requested, but if you can tolerate having `1a` without a `1b`, it will work.  But it requires that your data be properly sorted before running this.

```
library(dplyr)
dta %>%
  mutate(time_diff = c(-1, diff(time)),
         new_time = (time_diff < 0),
         time_id = cumsum(new_time),
         row = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(time_id = time_id - (min(time_id) - 1),
         time_id = letters[time_id],
         id_f = paste0(id, time_id)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(id, time, row, id_f)
```

Answer (score 1):

I named the data frame z.

```
z$timediff <- c(0,diff(z$time)) < 0
z$iddiff <- c(0,diff(z$id))
z$timediffminusiddiff <- z$timediff - z$iddiff
z$cumsumtimediff <- cumsum(z$timediff)

z$haserr <- ave(z$timediffminusiddiff,z$id,FUN = max)
z$newnum <- letters[z$cumsumtimediff - ave(z$cumsumtimediff,z$id,FUN = min) + 1]
z[z$haserr == 1,'id'] <- paste0(z$id,z$newnum)[z$haserr == 1]
z[ ,c('id','time')]
```

You could squeeze this together into less lines, but then it's harder to read.